# Spring Value: почему некорректно видит переменные?

Tags: java, spring

Я вынес все данные в properties, например, с такими полями:

```
email.content.charset=utf-8
```

Я создал отдельный класс с пропертями, ResourcesProperties, в котором у меня есть это поле и геттер:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResourcesProperties {

    @Value("${email.content.charset}")
    private String emailCharset;

    public String getEmailCharset() {
        return emailCharset;
    }
}
```

Проперти-файл сканируется спрингом:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:/properties/mail.properties"})
```

Я автовайрю класс проперти в нужный мне класс:

```
@Autowired
private ResourcesProperties properties;
```

и вывожу на экран:

```
System.out.println(properties.getEmailCharset());
```

Результат:

```
${email.content.charset}
```

Делаю то же самое через Environment:

```
System.out.println(environment.getProperty("email.content.charset"));
```

Результат:

```
utf-8
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш класс `ResourcesProperties` след код.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConf() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Если не инициализировать `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` то считыватся через аннотацию `property` не будет

Comment: Отлично, заработало!